# Install iOS app developed using Visual Studio 2015 Xamarin to iPhone directly

Tags: ios, iphone, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I have developed a iOS app using Visual Studio 2015 Xamarin. Right now I dont have a mac system in place. Is there any way I can install the app to iPhone directly and test.

We can do the same for android device by directly installing APK to device.

Best regards
Anup

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but you need **distribution** certificate and after create **ipa** so you can install ipa in your device using itune on window system

Comment: Can you please explain little more. I am new to iOS world. Or can you share any link that guide me little more.

Comment: http://lessons.livecode.com/m/4069/l/32957-how-do-i-create-a-distribution-profile-for-ios

Answer (score 0):

sure you can. please see this article on which setting to do.
You basically have to chose an ios device as debug goal instead of the simulator
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging_in_xamarin_ios/

additionally this needs the same basic prequises than installing unsigned applications on ios.

Comment: I think I need a mac for this. My goal is not to do debugging. I dont have a mac system. So, need to directly install to iPhone. The link you shared is for how to do debugging

Comment: to generate any kind of executable a mac is needed

Answer (score 0):

If we consider the xamarin application the ipa file itself will generated on build server

You'll need mac any how I guess.